# pip install on archive fails to install git dependency

Tags: python, github, pip, setuptools, requirements.txt

I have a package that depends on the following github project: https://github.com/jbittencourt/python-escpos.git (not to be confused with the python-escpos package that exists on PyPi).

So in my package's requirements.txt I have `git+https://github.com/jbittencourt/python-escpos.git#egg=escpos`.

When I install my package using either `pip install -r requirements.txt` or with `python setup.py install` (which parses the same requirements.txt file for its install_requires parameter) - everything works great.

The problem is when I archive my package into mypackage.tar.gz. After archiving the very same code that worked a second ago, and running `pip install mypackage.tar.gz` I get the following error:

```
Collecting escpos (from shopic==1.10.0)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement escpos (from shopic==1.10.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for escpos (from shopic==1.10.0)
```

From playing around with it, I noticed that w/e I type after the "#egg=" part of `git+https://github.com/jbittencourt/python-escpos.git#egg=escpos` - it simply tries to get it off PyPi (and fails, in this case). E.g. if I wrote (for some odd reason) `git+https://github.com/jbittencourt/python-escpos.git#egg=requests` it'd install the `requests` package.

I don't understand why it works differently when all I do is pack the files in a .tar.gz, and I have no idea how to work around it. I cannot use one of the other installation methods because I have another package that has this one as its dependency, and when I run pip install on that package, it has this tar.gz file as one of its dependencies, and so it fails.

Any ideas why this happens and how to resolve it? Thanks.

---

**Edit**: Here's my setup.py for reference:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import pip

links = []
requires = []

requirements = pip.req.parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=pip.download.PipSession())

for item in requirements:
    # we want to handle package names and also repo urls
    if getattr(item, 'url', None):  # older pip has url
        links.append(str(item.url))
    if getattr(item, 'link', None): # newer pip has link
        links.append(str(item.link))
    if item.req:
        requires.append(str(item.req))

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='1.1.0',
      description='My Package',
      author='EK',
      author_email='me@example.com',
      url='http://www.example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages(),
      package_data={'': ['*.jar']},
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=requires,
      dependency_links=links)
```

Comment: With newer versions of `pip` you need to use `--process-dependency-links` and use `dependency_links` in setup.py.

Comment: IMO this is a misfeature of `pip` and is better avoided altogether.

Comment: @jordanm I added my setup.py for reference - I already use dependency_links. I tried adding the `--process-dependency-links` flag but it still didn't work :(.

Comment: @wim My full scenario is that I have an external tool installing a package with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, that has a dependency on this package above. It expects to find it as a tar.gz in a given URL. So I can't control the installation flow - I need this to work somehow.

Comment: You're misusing `requirements.txt`.  It is for pinning versions.  It is NOT to be used to generate values passed to `install_requires`.

Comment: The best approach will be to ask the author on github to make a distribution of the package.  If they won't, or you need it immediately, then fork the repository and release your own distribution.

Comment: @wim I created my own distribution (.whl file) and put that in the requirements.txt file instead. Is that what you meant for me to do? It still fails the same way (when running `pip install mypackage.tar.gz`) and works when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` after unpacking the .tar.gz).